# How can I use SQLIO Stress Test to define the max capacity of my SQL subsystem?

Tags: sql-server, performance, stress-testing

I am looking for an article about Disk Subsystem Stress for SQL Server. So I can do better capacity management ! I already know the basis but I am looking for an "how to" for dummies who wants to install and do some reporting and trending using Excel !

Thanks

Comment: This might be a serverfault.com question...

Comment: There's really two parts to this question - how to use SQLIO to define the max throughput of your storage, and how to use Excel to do reporting and trending on data.  You may want to consider these tasks separately, as there is no start-to-finish using Excel.  Typically SQL Server DBAs will choose to use SQL Server rather than Excel for their reporting and trending.  If there's anything more specific you have, post it & we can definitely help out.

Comment: Thanks Brent, I had the same reflexion about using Reporting Services instead of Excel. Reporting Services requires a bit more knowlege forensic for my part.

Answer (score 3):

Google delivers: http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/SAN_Performance_Tuning_with_SQLIO
If you are doing any kind of stress testing on a SAN, be sure not to affect other production server's performance.

Comment: Which is why I could heartily recommend it without even watching it.